# jQuery only works when page is refreshed

Tags: jquery

When I put my webpages that are connected to this jQuery code (below) the image slider does not work unless I refresh the page first, and then when I click the arrows on the image slider it goes through the images. Does anyone have any insight on what I need to change in this code to make it work?? Thanks!!

```
$(window).load(function(){

// We are listening to the window.load event, so we can be sure
// that the images in the slideshow are loaded properly

// Testing whether the current browser supports the canvas element:
var supportCanvas = 'getContext' in document.createElement('canvas');

// The canvas manipulations of the images are CPU intensive,
// this is why we are using setTimeout to make them asynchronous
// and improve the responsiveness of the page.

var slides = $('#slideshow li'),
    current = 0,
    slideshow = {width:0,height:0};

setTimeout(function(){

    window.console && window.console.time && console.time('Generated In');

    if(supportCanvas){
        $('#slideshow img').each(function(){

            if(!slideshow.width){
                // Taking the dimensions of the first image:
                slideshow.width = this.width;
                slideshow.height = this.height;
            }

            // Rendering the modified versions of the images:
            createCanvasOverlay(this);
        });
    }

    window.console && window.console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd('Generated In');

    $('#slideshow .arrow').click(function(){
        var li          = slides.eq(current),
            canvas      = li.find('canvas'),
            nextIndex   = 0;

        // Depending on whether this is the next or previous
        // arrow, calculate the index of the next slide accordingly.

        if($(this).hasClass('next')){
            nextIndex = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
        }
        else {
            nextIndex = current <= 0 ? slides.length-1 : current-1;
        }

        var next = slides.eq(nextIndex);

        if(supportCanvas){

            // This browser supports canvas, fade it into view:

            canvas.fadeIn(function(){

                // Show the next slide below the current one:
                next.show();
                current = nextIndex;

                // Fade the current slide out of view:
                li.fadeOut(function(){
                    li.removeClass('slideActive');
                    canvas.hide();
                    next.addClass('slideActive');
                });
            });
        }
        else {

            // This browser does not support canvas.
            // Use the plain version of the slideshow.
            current=nextIndex;
            next.addClass('slideActive').show();
            li.removeClass('slideActive').hide();
        }
    });

},100);

// This function takes an image and renders
// a version of it similar to the Overlay blending
// mode in Photoshop. 
// **NOTE: REMOVED COLOR CHANGES

function createCanvasOverlay(image){

    var canvas          = document.createElement('canvas'),
        canvasContext   = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Make it the same size as the image
    canvas.width = slideshow.width;
    canvas.height = slideshow.height;

    // Drawing the default version of the image on the canvas:
    canvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0);


    // Taking the image data and storing it in the imageData array:
    var imageData   = canvasContext.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height),
        data        = imageData.data;

    // Putting the modified imageData back to the canvas.
    canvasContext.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

    // Inserting the canvas in the DOM, before the image:
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas,image);
}

//end of window load    
});
```

Comment: Why are you not using `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Jan you mean `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Or for that matter `$(document).ready()`, or it's shorter version `$()`

Comment: `$().ready(){` or `$(){` does the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I've had bad results with `$(window).load()` in the past. My experience is that often times the load event won't fire at all, for example if the browser considers the page cached. This would explain why a hard refresh appears to fix your problem.

My recommendation is not to rely on it, and to use `$(document).ready()` instead.

Comment: I tried using     $document.ready() instead, and now even refreshing the page doesn't make the slider work. Could it be the way the images are being called to load?

Comment: @Shub I am having the same problem and changing $(window).load() to $(document).ready() didn't work for me either and didn't make the slider load at all on refresh... Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: @starkey01 This might solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links