# Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

I ran into an issue in my Rails 4 app while trying to organize JS files "the rails way". They were previously scattered across different views. I organized them into separate files and compile them with the assets pipeline. However, I just learned that jQuery's "ready" event doesn't fire on subsequent clicks when turbo-linking is turned on. The first time you load a page it works. But when you click a link, anything inside the `ready( function($) {` won't get executed (because the page doesn't actually load again). Good explanation: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-position-of/18770219?noredirect=1#18770219).

So my question is: What is the right way to ensure that jQuery events work properly while turbo-links are on? Do you wrap the scripts in a Rails-specific listener? Or maybe rails has some magic that makes it unnecessary? The docs are a bit vague on how this should work, especially with respect to loading multiple files via the manifest(s) like application.js.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I just learned of another option for solving this problem. If you load [the `jquery-turbolinks` gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) it will bind the Rails Turbolinks events to the `document.ready` events so you can write your jQuery in the usual way. You just add `jquery.turbolinks` right after `jquery` in the js manifest file (by default: `application.js`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Exactly what I need. The rails way. Convention.

Comment: Acording to the [documentation](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks), you should add `//= require jquery.turbolinks` to the manifest (e.g. application.js).

Comment: your answer mixed with Meltemi's one IS the perfect solution

Comment: Very clean and useful, especially when you have integrated some third party theme along with its js files. Thanks!

Comment: @wildmonkey the two answers are mutually exclusive. 0.o

Comment: thanks @gwho I forgot to update my comment few months ago when I had this issue. You're right!

Comment: This gem doesn't seem to execute with AJAX calls. how would you do that?

Comment: This answers is the correct one. Adding gem jquery-turbolinks helped me with this issue.

Comment: You need to restart your rails server when you add this gem

Comment: I still get issues getting turbolinks to work properly with select2 using this.

Comment: This somehow still doesn't work for me. I've added it to my gemfile, I bundled installed. I added "// = requre jquery.turbolinks" to the application.js.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Please note that Rails 4 is now defaulting to Turbolinks 5 which, in turn, is not supported by jquery.turbolinks! See https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks/issues/56

Comment: @sebastian - thanks for this important clarification.  So, for now, the best solution would be to remove turbolinks from the app.

Comment: @Anwar - I remove it from Rails entirely now, to avoid issues with js not working in many cases.

Answer (score 561):

Here's what I do...
CoffeeScript:

```
ready = ->

  ...your coffeescript goes here...

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

last line listens for page load which is what turbo links will trigger.

**Edit**...adding Javascript version (per request):

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

**Edit 2**...For Rails 5 (Turbolinks 5) `page:load` becomes `turbolinks:load` and will be even fired on initial load. So we can just do the following:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

});
```

Comment: Is that coffee script? I haven't learned it yet. Is there a js or jQuery equivalent to your example?

Comment: Think I got it: `var ready = function() { ... } $(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)` Is there any concern for *both* `.ready` and `'page:load'` getting triggered?

Comment: @Emerson there is a very useful website, with an explicit name: http://js2coffee.org

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks. I was just looking at it. I still don't entirely get the appeal of coffeescript but it looks pretty straight-forward, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: 1. What is the difference between using page:load and page:change 
2. What is the difference between using $(document).on and $(document).bind ?

Comment: One problem with this approach is that the `ready` function will be called twice.

Comment: doesn't it only get called when it needs to though?  It calls it when the document is ready and then it calls it when the page loads (which we are assuming came from a turbo-link trigger).  Right?

Comment: I can confirm that the ready function does **not** get called twice. If it's a hard refresh, _only_ the `ready` event is fired. If it's a turbolinks load, _only_ the `page:load` event is fired. It's impossible for both `ready` and `page:load` to be fired on the same page.

Comment: Look at SDP's answer to his own question, it's the right way to do it. This will work but it's not the best way.

Comment: The `page:change` event seems to work for both hard refresh and turbolinks load. Anyone know a downside to using this instead of `ready` _and_ `page:load`? The only one I can think of that might be a possibility is that `page:change` is an earlier event so the DOM may not be loaded all the way when your code is run. Not sure though.

Comment: This can be shortened to `$(document).on('ready page:load', ready)`, no?

Comment: FYI You can also apply this for multiple events `page:load` and `ready` by including a space-separated string for the first argumet. `$(document).on('page:load ready', ready);` The second argument is simply a function, which happens to be named `ready`, following this answer's example.

Comment: `$(document).on('page:load ready', ready);'` is the way to go

Comment: ```$(document).on('page:load', functionName);``` is definitely the way to go. Works with javaScript and jQuery

Comment: This solution didn't work for me in Rails 4.1. Scroll down below for a solution with jquery.turbolinks that works.

Comment: This DOES work for me in Rails 4.2.6 -- maybe it doesn't have to be Rails 5?

Comment: For Rails 4.2.7, and Turbolinks 5, it looks like turbolinks will intercept `page:load` and only fire `turbolinks:load`. It works for me when I listen for the latter, not for the former. But Chrome confirmed that the browser did in fact fire `page:load`

Comment: `$(document).ready(ready)` `$(document).on('page:load', ready)` kept firing twice for me. `$(document).on('page:load ready', ready)` works the way I expect it to.

Comment: If you have a code called on `ready` and `turbolinks:load`, it will be called twice. It's logic because if the code executed after the `turbolinks:load` event is called, it means that he has necessarily gone through the `ready` event. If you want that your code works on a page without turbolinks and on a page with, you need to put your code in a function, then do something like `if (typeof Turbolinks === 'undefined') { $(document).ready(yourFunction); } else { $(document).on('turbolinks:load', yourFunction) }`. So your code will be executed  properly on a view with and without turbolinks

Answer (score 200):

Recently I found the most clean and easy to understand way of dealing with it:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  # Actions to do
```

**OR**

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
  // Actions to do
});
```

**EDIT**
If you have [delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) bound to the `document`, make sure you attach them outside of the `ready` function, otherwise they will get rebound on every `page:load` event (causing the same functions to be run multiple times). For example, if you have any calls like this:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  ...
  $(document).on 'click', '.button', ->
    ...
  ...
```

Take them out of the `ready` function, like this:

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  ...
  ...

$(document).on 'click', '.button', ->
  ...
```

Delegated events bound to the `document` do not need to be bound on the `ready` event.

Comment: This is much simpler than the accepted answer of creating a separate `ready()` function. Bonus upvotes for the explanation of binding delegated events outside of the `ready` function.

Comment: On disadvantage of this method is that `$(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.` [jquery/ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @Dezi @mfazekas Would this solution work if you're using earlier versions of jQuery, and WITHOUT the jquery-turbolinks gem? Or is the `ready` portion made invalid BY using the gem?

Comment: The simplest and easiest way to do it. It supports js code distributed in multiple files and I don't have to bother in which order they were included. Much cleaner than the variable assignment.

Comment: You should probably use "page:change" instead of "page:load", as [the former is fired whether the page is loaded from the server or from client-side cache](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#events).

Answer (score 90):

Found this in the [Rails 4 documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks), similar to DemoZluk's solution but slightly shorter:

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  # Actions to do
```

OR

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  // Actions to do
});
```

If you have external scripts that call `$(document).ready()` or if you can't be bothered rewriting all your existing JavaScript, then this gem allows you to keep using `$(document).ready()` with TurboLinks: https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Answer (score 80):

As per the new [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks), the correct way is to do the following:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   console.log('(document).turbolinks:load')
});
```

or, in coffeescript:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
alert "page has loaded!"
```

Do not listen to the event `$(document).ready` and only one event will be fired. No surprises, no need to use the **jquery.turbolinks** gem.

This works with rails 4.2 and above, not only rails 5.

Comment: nice this worked for me. Tried solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881384/jquery-gets-loaded-only-on-page-refresh-in-rails-4-application but did not work for some reason. Now I load on turbolinks:load instead

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct solution. All the other answers are old

Comment: Can anyone confirm that `"turbolinks:load"` event works in Rails 4.2? The `turbolinks:` event prefix was introduced in the **New** Turbolinks and isn't used in Rails 4.2 IIRC which uses Turbolinks **Classic**. Consider trying `"page:change"` if `"turbolinks:load"` doesn't work on your pre-Rails 5 app. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events

Comment: @EliotSykes The guide has not been updated. Rails 4.2 now uses https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks instead of turbolinks-classic. And in any case, this depends on what you have specified in your Gemfile.
Hope you will confirm the same soon :)

Comment: Thanks @vedant1811. At time of writing, I'm confirming that a new Rails 4.2.7 app uses Turbolinks 5 (not turbolinks-classic). Developers reading this - check your Gemfile.lock for the turbolinks version used. If it is less then 5.0 then use `page:change` or upgrade turbolinks. Also found this, may be relevant to some, where turbolinks translates events to the old event names: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/v5.0.0/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee

Comment: Works perfect! Using rails 5

Comment: Does the `alert "page has loaded!"` need to be indented to be actually run by the callback function?

Comment: @mbigras: No. You can put anything there and it will run

Comment: @EliotSykes I'm using rails 4.2.8 and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 10):

**NOTE: See @SDP's answer for a clean, built-in solution**

I fixed it as follows:

make sure you include application.js before the other app dependent js files get included by changing the include order as follows:

```
// in application.js - make sure `require_self` comes before `require_tree .`
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Define a global function that handles the binding in `application.js`

```
// application.js
window.onLoad = function(callback) {
  // binds ready event and turbolink page:load event
  $(document).ready(callback);
  $(document).on('page:load',callback);
};
```

Now you can bind stuff like:

```
// in coffee script:
onLoad ->
  $('a.clickable').click => 
    alert('link clicked!');

// equivalent in javascript:
onLoad(function() {
  $('a.clickable').click(function() {
    alert('link clicked');
});
```

Comment: This seems the cleanest since you only have to add this in one place, not every coffeescript file.  Nice work!

Comment: @sled So is this saying to use SDP's method of using the gem and this code? Or is this an answer that doesn't use the gem?

Comment: forget this answer and use SDP's solution.

Comment: @sled Is it possible to combine SDP's solution with the notion of putting the call only in one place?

Comment: @gwho: As SDP's answer shows, turbolinks hooks up to the `ready` event, this means you can use the "standard" way of initializing: `$(document).ready(function() { /* do your init here */});`. Your init code should be called when the complete page is loaded (-> without turbolinks) and your init code should be executed again when you load a page via turbolinks. If you want to execute some code ONLY when a turbolink has been used: `$(document).on('page:load', function() { /* init only for turbolinks */});`

Comment: @sled I see. init code is simply code you wish to execute. So I suppose `$(document).on('ready page:load ', function(){} );` wouldn't work for the `ready`, as documented in the gem's github readme.

Answer (score 9):

None of the above works for me, I solved this by not using jQuery's $(document).ready, but use addEventListener instead.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$(document).on 'ready turbolinks:load', ->
  console.log '(document).turbolinks:load'
```

Comment: That is the only solution that works for me on every and each browser, for Turbolinks >= 5 and that triggers both on first page load and also when you click any links (with turbolinks).

That is the case because while Chrome triggers `turbolinks:load` on the very first page load, Safari does not and the hacky way to fix it (triggering `turbolinks:load` on `application.js`) obviously breaks Chrome (which fires twice with this).

This is the correct answer. 
Definitely go with the 2 events `ready` and `turbolinks:load`.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  // your code here
})
```

[from turbolinks doc](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads).

Answer (score 3):

Either use the

```
$(document).on "page:load", attachRatingHandler
```

or use jQuery's .on function to achieve the same effect

```
$(document).on 'click', 'span.star', attachRatingHandler
```

see here for more details: http://srbiv.github.io/2013/04/06/rails-4-my-first-run-in-with-turbolinks.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a variable to save the "ready" function and bind it to the events, you might want to trigger the `ready` event whenever `page:load` triggers.

```
$(document).on('page:load', function() {
  $(document).trigger('ready');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have done to ensure things aren't executed twice:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
     // ... init things, just do not bind events ...
     $(document).off("page:change");
});
```

I find using the `jquery-turbolinks` gem or combining `$(document).ready` and `$(document).on("page:load")` or using `$(document).on("page:change")` by itself behaves unexpectedly--especially if you're in development.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you mean by behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: If I have just a simple alert without the `$(document).off` bit in that anonymous "page:change" function above it will obviously alert when I get to that page. But at least in development running WEBrick, it will also alert when I click a link to another page. Event worse, it alerts twice when I then click a link back to the original page.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following [article](https://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/jquery-document-ready-events-and-turbolinks/) which worked great for me and details the use of the following:

```
var load_this_javascript = function() { 
  // do some things 
}
$(document).ready(load_this_javascript)
$(window).bind('page:change', load_this_javascript)
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured I'd leave this here for those upgrading to [Turbolinks 5](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks): the easiest way to fix your code is to go from:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  // Your JS here
}
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

to:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  // Your JS here
}
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

Reference: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/9#issuecomment-184717346

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(ready)  

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Actually, this answer is incorrect. The `turbolinks:load` event fires for the initial page load as well as after following links. If you attach an event both to the standard `ready` event and the `turbolinks:load` event, it will fire twice when you first visit a page.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As @alexanderbird said, it causes ``ready`` to fire twice on subsequent page loads. Please change or remove it.

Comment: @alexanderbird Your comment solved one of the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

## Update Turbolinks -> Hotwired Turbo (2021+)

[Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) has been archived and is now maintained as part of [hotwired](https://hotwired.dev/) under [turbo](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo).

If you're using the new version, you can listen for turbo load like this:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("turbo:load", (e) {
  console.log("turbo:load", e)
});
```

Here's the full list of [events they broadcast](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events) on the document element:

- `turbo:click`
- `turbo:before-visit`
- `turbo:visit`
- `turbo:submit-start`
- `turbo:before-fetch-request`
- `turbo:before-fetch-response`
- `turbo:submit-end`
- `turbo:before-cache`
- `turbo:before-render`
- `turbo:before-stream-render`
- `turbo:render`
- `turbo:load`
- `turbo:before-frame-render`
- `turbo:frame-render`
- `turbo:frame-load`
- `turbo:frame-render`
- `turbo:frame-missing`
- `turbo:fetch-request-error`

Answer (score 1):

Tested so many solution finally came to this.
This many your code is definitely not called twice.

```js
      var has_loaded=false;
      var ready = function() {
        if(!has_loaded){
          has_loaded=true;
           
          // YOURJS here
        }
      }

      $(document).ready(ready);
      $(document).bind('page:change', ready);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following for my rails 4 projects:

In `application.js`

```
function onInit(callback){
    $(document).ready(callback);
    $(document).on('page:load', callback);
}
```

Then in the rest of the .js files, instead of using `$(function (){})` I call `onInit(function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

First, install `jquery-turbolinks` gem. And then, don't forget to move your included Javascript files from end of body of your `application.html.erb` to its `<head>`.

As [described here](https://coderwall.com/p/ypzfdw/faster-page-loads-with-turbolinks), if you have put the application javascript link in the footer for speed optimization reasons, you will need to move it into the  tag so that it loads before the content in the  tag. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found my functions doubled when using a function for `ready` and `turbolinks:load` so I used,

```
var ready = function() {
  // you code goes here
}

if (Turbolinks.supported == false) {
  $(document).on('ready', ready);
};
if (Turbolinks.supported == true) {
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
};
```

That way your functions don't double if turbolinks is supported!